# Kubernetes - Pod Remains in ContainerCreating Status

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, weave

I am new to all things Kubernetes so still have much to learn.

Have created a two node Kubernetes cluster and both nodes (master and worker) are ready to do work which is good:

```
[monkey@k8s-dp1 nginx-test]# kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s-dp1   Ready     master    2h        v1.9.1
k8s-dp2   Ready     <none>    2h        v1.9.1
```

Also, all Kubernetes Pods look okay:

```
[monkey@k8s-dp1 nginx-test]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-k8s-dp1                      1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-dp1            1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-dp1   1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system   kube-dns-86cc76f8d-9jh2w          3/3       Running   0          2h
kube-system   kube-proxy-65mtx                  1/1       Running   1          2h
kube-system   kube-proxy-wkkdm                  1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-dp1            1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system   weave-net-6sbbn                   2/2       Running   0          2h
kube-system   weave-net-hdv9b                   2/2       Running   3          2h
```

However, if I try to create a new deployment in the cluster, the deployment gets created but its pod fails to go into the appropriate RUNNING state. e.g.

```
[monkey@k8s-dp1 nginx-test]# kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/docs/tasks/run-application/deployment.yaml
deployment "nginx-deployment" created

[monkey@k8s-dp1 nginx-test]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
default       nginx-deployment-569477d6d8-f42pz   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          5s
default       nginx-deployment-569477d6d8-spjqk   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          5s
kube-system   etcd-k8s-dp1                        1/1       Running             0          3h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-dp1              1/1       Running             0          3h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-dp1     1/1       Running             0          3h
kube-system   kube-dns-86cc76f8d-9jh2w            3/3       Running             0          3h
kube-system   kube-proxy-65mtx                    1/1       Running             1          2h
kube-system   kube-proxy-wkkdm                    1/1       Running             0          3h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-dp1              1/1       Running             0          3h
kube-system   weave-net-6sbbn                     2/2       Running             0          2h
kube-system   weave-net-hdv9b                     2/2       Running             3          2h
```

I am not sure how to figure out what the problem is but if I for example do a `kubectl get ev`, I can see the following suspect event:

```
<invalid>   <invalid>    1         nginx-deployment-569477d6d8-f42pz.15087c66386edf5d   Pod
             Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   kubelet, k8s-dp2        Failed create pod sandbox.
```

But I don't know where to go from here. I can also see that the nginx docker image itself never appears in `docker images`.

How do I find out more about the problem? Am I missing something fundamental in the kubernetes setup?

--- NEW INFO ---

For background info in case it helps...

Kubernetes nodes are running on CentOS 7 VMs hosted on Windows 10 hyper-v.

--- NEW INFO ---

Running `kubectl describe pods` shows the following Warning:

```
Warning  NetworkNotReady         1m                             kubelet, k8s-dp2  network is not ready: [runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized]
```

--- NEW INFO ---

Switched off the Hyper-v VMs running Kubernetes for the night after my day job hours were over and on my return to the office this morning, I powered up the Kubernetes VMs once again to carry on and, for about 15 mins, the command:

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` was still showing `ContainerCreating` for those nginx pods the same as yesterday but, right now, the command is now showing all pods as `Running` including the nginx pods... i.e. the problem solved itself after a full reboot of both master and worker node VMs.

I now did another full reboot again and all pods are showing as Running which is good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doing a full reboot of both VMs that are running the Kubernetes master node and Kubernetes worker node got the Pods to all show as `Running` (NOTE: After first reboot, it took about 15-20 mins for the pods in question to go into a `Running` state and, on subsequent reboot, the pods in question went into `Running` state relatively much quicker... 3-5 mins).

Comment: In my case starting with a node cordon and drain and then restarting that node worked. the node itself was clogged up for some reason. I couldn't start a basic Nginx pod without errors in kubelet log. even a systemctl status kubelet took minutes and sometimes failed. Start with the node giving you issues and then a complete reboot if needed. Oh, and I use Ubuntu servers so it's not just Windows that has running too long.

Comment: My original post and this comment's answer is/was from years ago and indeed, it was a k8s trial that run on Centos OSes running on Windows Hyper-v vms for a specific customer. These days, most k8s clusters I work with run on bare metal Ubuntu OSes and we experience no such problems with those. K8s runs smoothly these days without any networking or any other types of hiccups whatsoever.

Answer (score 40):

Use `kubectl describe pod <name>` to see more info

Comment: Added output from your suggested which shows `cni config uninitialized` Warning. See post edit for details.

Comment: The CNI warning indicates that your internal cluster network isn't operating correctly. Depending on what you've chosen for the cluster network and where it resides, there may be a routing conflict which isn't allowing the containers to be pulled and started. Make sure you don't have conflicting networks. You may find more useful debugging tips at https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/

Comment: For my case, `describe pod <name> ` give not found.  The pod has not started yet. How to get the info in this case?

Comment: Are you saying that when you list pods you can see it with creating status but when you describe it's not there?

Answer (score 12):

Using `kubectl describe pod` would show all the events. In some cases, the deployment might be still pulling the docker images from remote, so the status would be still shown as `ContainerCreating`

Answer (score 10):

Just sharing that this command helped a lot to find out my problem with ContainerCreating Status:

```
kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Answer (score 4):

try to `systemctl restart kubelet.service`

Answer (score 4):

You can delete de pod, it will be recreated automatically.

```
kubectl delete pod -n namespace podname
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to missing Secret or say ConfigMap in deployments namespace

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue yesterday. When I describe those pods in ContainerCreating status, the problem was with CNI, it was failing and pods stays in ContainerCreating status. So I delete the CNI from the controlplane and redeploy it. All the pods will change its status within a minute to running status.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `kubectl describe` command on the deployment to be sure as to the events going on or you can run the `describe` command on the pods that the deployment is spinning up.

Sometimes you may not be having enough resources in your cluster. Check what you using `kubectl top` command on the pods running to see if one of them is exhausting all of your resources.

I hope this is helpful enough

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue but problem with my side was that cluster took too much time to pull the image, may a quick cluster restart can help to make the process faster

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue When I list the pods some were in ContainerCreating status,there could be below issues which would be visible in describe command.
Reasons:-
image pulling issue (or secret is not present) / configmap is not available etc.

reasons can be visible in below 2 commands.

kubectl describe pod  -n namespace

systemctl status kubelet (here you will get all connection errors with repo)

usually this issue get due to image pull interruption.

so restart the below 2 sevrices in sequences.

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker

sudo systemctl reload docker

sudo systemctl restart kubelet (here we get all live connection logs)

Hope it will help.